# Adding Comment in textarea and displaying text with Edit and delete buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have textarea with save and cancel buttons for updating textarea text in mysql DB.

Initially my MYSQL db

```
ID  text
1   NULL
```

If i enter some text in textarea i'm updating my mysql db text with entered value currently i'm able to achieve it but my requirment is once i entered text in textarea it should update my db and that text value should display with EDIT and DELETE buttons.

on clicking EDIT button it should open up textarea with save and cancel buttons. can somebody aid me out how to achieve it Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/a32yjx0k/

**HTML**

```
<div id="b_news">
<form method="post" action="">
    </div>
    <div class="breaking_news_content">
        <div>
            <form method="post" action="">
            <div>
                <div>
                  <textarea id="breaking_news_text" class="breaking_news_text" rows="6" cols="50"  placeholder="Add text here..." required></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input  type="submit" class=" save_breaking_news" value="Save Changes"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Cancel" class=" breaking_news_cancel">
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function(){
    $(".save_breaking_news").click(function(){
        var textcontent = $('.breaking_news_text').val();
        if(textcontent == '')
        {
            alert("Enter Some Text...");
            $('.breaking_news_text').focus();
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.php",
                data:{
                    textcontent:textcontent

                },
                success:function(response){
                    alert('breaking news successfully updated');
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['textcontent']))
    {
            $breaking_news = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['textcontent']);
            $sql = "update breakingnews set text='".$breaking_news."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    }   
?>
```

Comment: with text-area you have to use `$(".CLASS").text();` instead  of `$(".CLASS").val();`

Comment: @BushraShahid Thank You For useful Info! will u help me out in displaying entered value with edit and delete buttons Thanks!

Comment: 1.) for update a post u have to know the post ID where is your post id.. Which post you want to edit..?

Comment: 2.) you have to use input type button instead of submit because you want to achieve the task using ajax.

Comment: I have only 2 columns ID and TEXT with single row value 1/NULL(text) as soon as i enter value save and cancel button should replace with edit and delete buttons Thanks!

Comment: yes you have to use this ID to update your post.. And if you want to insert then you can use insert Query rather than Update

Comment: Thank You for ur useful Info!!

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function(){
    $(".save_breaking_news").click(function(){
        var textcontent = $('.breaking_news_text').text();
        if(textcontent == '')
        {
            alert("Enter Some Text...");
            $('.breaking_news_text').focus();
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.php",
                data:{
                    textcontent:textcontent

                },
                success:function(response){
                    alert('breaking news successfully updated');
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

To get textbox use (class/id).text();

Comment: Thank you for ur valuable info and time but how to replace save and cancel buttons with edit and delete buttons Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your DIV

```
<div id="b_news">
<form method="post" action="">
    </div>
    <div class="breaking_news_content">
        <div>
            <form method="post" action="">
            <div>
                <div>
                  <textarea id="breaking_news_text" class="breaking_news_text" rows="6" cols="50"  placeholder="Add text here..." required></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input  type="hidden" id="post_ID" value="2"/>
                <input  type="button" class=" save_breaking_news" value="Save Changes"/>
                <input type="button" value="Cancel" class=" breaking_news_cancel">
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

YOUR SCRIPT SHOULD BE LIKE THIS

```
$(function(){
    $(".save_breaking_news").click(function(){
        var textcontent = $('.breaking_news_text').text();
        if(textcontent == '')
        {
            alert("Enter Some Text...");
            $('.breaking_news_text').focus();
        }
        else
        {
            var postID=$("#post_ID").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: 'textcontent=' + drvNo+"id="+postID,
                success:function(response){
                    alert('breaking news successfully updated');
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

YOUR PHP CODE FOR UPDATE

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['textcontent']))
    {
            $breaking_news = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['textcontent']);
            $sql = "update breakingnews set text='".$breaking_news."' Where id='".$_POST['id']."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    }   
?>
```

AND IF YOU WANT TO INSERT POST YOUR CODE SHOULD BE LIKE THIS:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['textcontent']) && !isset($_POST['id']))
    {
            $breaking_news = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['textcontent']);
            $sql = "insert into <TBL NAME> `text` values ('".$_POST['textcontent']."')";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    }   
?>
```

Comment: Thank You So much for your valuable time and solving my issue Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code everything is fine. Instead of calling function use .keyup() function in Jquery.

```
 $("#breaking_news_text").keyup(function(){
        var textcontent = $('.breaking_news_text').val();
        if(textcontent == '')
        {
            alert("Enter Some Text...");
            $('.breaking_news_text').focus();
        }
        else
        {
            alert(textcontent);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.php",
                data:
                {
                    textcontent:textcontent
                },
                success:function(response)
                {
                    alert('breaking news successfully updated');
                }
            });
        }
    return false;
});
```

and when you going to cancel please use input type="reset"

```
<input type="reset" value="Cancel" class=" breaking_news_cancel">
```

Comment: Thank You so much for ur valuable time and suggestion!!